# CVS Remove Directory

Tags: cvs

I started to create a new directory which I intended to add and commit to CVS. I created a directory, and executed cvs add ./templates/ which worked. Then I never committed. cvs status still sees the directory, but now I want to remove the directory. When I run cvs status I receive the following:

```
$ cvs status
cvs status: Examining templates
cvs status: in directory templates:
cvs [status aborted]: there is no version here; do 'cvs checkout' first
```

When I try to run cvs remove:

```
$ cvs remove ./templates/
cvs remove: Removing ./templates
cvs remove: in directory ./templates:
cvs [remove aborted]: there is no version here; do 'cvs checkout' first
```

When I try a cvs checkout:

```
$ cvs checkout ./templates/
cvs checkout: cannot find module `./templates' - ignored
```

Comment: Looks like you need to remove it directly on the server (carefully!).

Comment: @KeithThompson couldn't make heads or tails of that post, not the strongest with CVS. Would I delete just the actual dir then do a cvs commit? Or would I remove the dir and just run cvs update?

Comment: CVS apparently can't delete directories via the client interface. You have to delete the directory *on the server*. If you don't understand what that means, I'm afraid you're better off just leaving the directory in place.

Comment: @KeithThompson the repo/server and the working dir are both on the same server, just different paths. I attempted to delete the directory from the repo, but the same checkin and remove aborts occur. If I rmdir the working dir I receive "could not chdir to templates" and I can't cvs remove since no directory exists.

Comment: Try removing the entry from `CVS/Entries` in the working directory.

Comment: @KeithThompson That was it! Appreciate the help, looks like I did a similar enough command to Ljubomir Josifovski answer. Think they are close enough to be closed as similar even though his isn't the top answer?